# ssh: connect to host ********* port 22: Connection timed out

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, server, firewall

I have Ubuntu 22.04 newly installed on my laptop. I am trying to connect to a remote server and getting the following error:

```
ssh: connect to host  ********* port 22: Connection timed out
```

I tried some solutions which include,

- ping the IP address
- adding the IP address to the firewall using sudo ufw
- installing ssh and openssh

However, nothing seems to work. I'd be thankful if someone can help me to solve this problem.

Comment: This means networking is broken. run `ipconfig`(on windows) or `ifconfig`(linux) depending on the OS of your laptop & check whether you see the n/w interface of the VM  IP belonging to any subnet.

Comment: How would pinging solve the issue? What was the result of pinging the host?

Comment: @LinFelix
 I tried pinging because when I was searching for solutions some solutions stated that pinging may solve the issue. The output was only this line "PING <IP address>  (IP address) 56(84) bytes of data."

Answer (score 0):

If you can ping the server it can be the following causes:

1. The server is not answering ssh, sometimes ssh server is not up or it is answering in another port.
2. There is a firewall blocking your request.

You do not need to install the openssh server in your computer to access a remote hosts and normally outbound connections are allowed by ufw.

Answer (score -2):

```
ssh: connect to host  ********* port 22: Connection timed out
```

I have this kind of problem too I contact the server admin and said the operation system should be install again due to some problems

after re installing the problem solved try it it may works

Comment: Please edit your previous answer instead of posting a nearly identical second one.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).